# How can i get specific part of a string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get subsection of a string(url) that looks like this.
**https://justkidding.com/ids/09239849/dont-say-a-word** and i want to get **09239849**

*The length and value of the 09239849 (substring) varies but the string (url) structure remains the same.

I tried using replace method but i can only get **09239849/dont-say-a-word** from the string because everything after the substring (09239849) is dynamic

```
<!--mycode-->
<button onclick="myFunction()">View ID</button>
<script>
function myTrim(x) {
return x.replace('https://justkidding.com/ids/','');
}

function myFunction() {
var str = myTrim("https://justkidding.com/ids/09239849/dont-say-a-word");
alert(str);
}
</script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45641931/increment-a-number-in-a-string-based-on-the-substring-before-it-in-js/45642092#

Comment: You can do something like :

    const url = "https://justkidding.com/ids/09239849/dont-say-a-word";
    const id = url.match(/\/\d+\//g)[0].replace(/\//g, '');

This regex will help you to extract this kind of pattern. Hope it will help !

Comment: You can use string match and a regex : `function getNumberFromUrl(x) {return x.match(/\/(\d+)\//)[1]}`.  More info on regex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Tanx @yago your snippet did the trick. I wonder why my question was marked as duplicate cus the link referred was not in anyway related.